# Problem with PanGesture and object translation in Arkit Scene (Xamarin)

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, arkit

i'm new with Arkit and Xamarin enviroment.
I need help about the translation of SCNNode in scene using PanGesture.
I have used this guide to start my fist approach with PanGesture. [Guide](https://www.xamarinarkit.com/lesson/gestures/)

After that....

I used the help code, but I noticed that, as in the example, when I move an object in the scene it ONLY follows the X, Y axes.
In short, if the Cartesian axes of the ARkit scene are framed, with the Z of the camera pointing at the observer, everything works.
If the camera position is changed (the phone moves), how can I obtain the translation delta within the 3D space?

```
if (sender.State == UIGestureRecognizerState.Changed)
        {
            var translate = sender.TranslationInView(areaPanned);

            // Only allow movement vertically or horizontally [OK, but how can i obtain the XYZ value of delta in scene from XY of Viewport?]
            node.LocalTranslate(new SCNVector3((float)translate.X / 10000f, (float)-translate.Y / 10000, 0.0f));
        }
```

Following the opengl standard I thought of such a solution:
[Pseudo code]

scale/offset from 0...1 to -1...1 coordinate space

```
 var vS = new Coordinate(this.Scene.CurrentViewport.X, this.Scene.CurrentViewport.Y, 1.0);
    var vWH = new Coordinate(this.Scene.CurrentViewport.Width, this.Scene.CurrentViewport.Height, 1.0);
    var scrrenpos = new Coordinate(translate.X, -translate.Y, 1.0);
    var normalized = (scrrenpos - vS) / vWH;
```

After that i need matrix:

```
 var inversePM = (projection * modelView).inverse
```

where:

=> projection from ARCAmera.ProjectionMatrix

=> modelView from ARCamera.Transform

To finish:

```
var result = normalized * inversePM;
```

if I set the SCNNode position with this value nothing works :(

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!
here [Swift code](https://github.com/literalpie/ARKit-essentials-playgrounds/blob/master/PlaygroundBook/Chapters/Dragging.playgroundchapter/Pages/ARKitDrag.playgroundpage/Contents.swift) to translate in c#... works fine!